# Send some pdf files as email attachments stored in a db in c#

Tags: c#, list

I need to send some pdf files as email attachments stored in a database.

[image]

I need convert comma separated string into a `List<string>` and i have tried with this c# code:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        RecoveryAtt = reader["Att"].ToString();                                                                       
        string Commaseplist;
        string[] itemList = { RecoveryAtt.ToString() };
        Commaseplist = String.Join("; ", itemList);
        Response.Write(Commaseplist.ToString());

    }
}
```

But in output I have:

```
D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\019.pdf
```

And in email attachment is first only Pdf file...

This doesn't work cause returns a string[] without separator.

Please help.

Comment: are you absolutely the output is incorrect? could the result be cached?

Comment: thank you. I have deleted the cache; now and in email attachment is last only Pdf file...

Comment: What is the value of `RecoveryAtt` and `itemList`

Comment: Is: `D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\019.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick

```
string[] itemList = Regex.Split(RecoveryAtt, @"(?=D:)").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
Commaseplist = String.Join("; ", itemList);
Response.Write(Commaseplist);
```

Comment: `CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq: Have a look on the updated edit. :)

Comment: `Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq: You need to use `System.Linq namespace.` for where and you can eliminate that as well ... but the only problem will be you will have one extra element in your array.

Comment: thank you, but in email attachment is last only Pdf file... `mailMessagePlainText.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Commaseplist.ToString()));` anf the value of `RecoveryAtt` and `itemList` is `D:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\015.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\016.pdfD:\in‌​etpub\wwwroot\app\public\017.pdfD:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\public\018.pdfD:\inetpub\w‌​wwroot\app\public\019.pdf`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq: This will not change the values of `RecoveryAtt` and `itemList` but will change the value of `Commaseplist` ... you can ask a different question with your email code. and as it results your expected answer you can Upvote and accept it as answer. and dont forget to comment the link of new Question.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-creating the `itemList` array and the `Commaseplist` string every time you read a new row in the database and so loosing previous data.  The output is being outputted once a row and appended - you are not adding to the array.

Perhaps a better approach would be along the lines of:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    StringBuilder commaList = new StringBuilder();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        commaList.Append(reader["Att"].ToString());                                                                      
        commaList.Append(",");

    }
    commaList.Remove(commaList.Lenth-1,1);
    Response.Write(commaList.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thank you, but now I have this error in attachment pdf: `Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.`

Comment: That is probably then an issue with how you are dealing with the resultant output.  How are you attaching it to the email?